# Compile error building project with multiple flavors and Play Services

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, analytics

When trying to build a Play Services enabled project with multiple flavors, I get compile errors.  I think this might be related to my package names not matching, but I am not sure.  Anybody have any hints about what I am doing wrong?

I am using the newer gradle plugin that allows this ([per this GH issue](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/54#issuecomment-165824720))

I am seeing an error when I try to build multiple flavors:

```
Error:(115, 50) error: cannot find symbol variable global_tracker
```

I double checked the package names match my expectation, but wonder if I still am not correct.

My build.gradle looks like this:

```
productFlavors {
        app1 {
            applicationId "com.examplea.app"
            manifestPlaceholders = [domain:"examplea"]
        }
        imore {
            applicationId "com.exampleb.app"
            manifestPlaceholders = [domain:"exampleb"]
        }
        crackberry {
            applicationId "com.examplec.app"
            manifestPlaceholders = [domain:"examplec"]
        }
```

an example of one of my *google-services.json* files (which is located at main/src/examplea) is:

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_id": "",
    "project_number": "",
    "name": ""
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:10908349452:android:bb075abfhadshfjd",
        "client_id": "android:com.examplea.app",
        "client_type": 1,
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.examplea.app"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [],
      "api_key": [],
      "services": {
        "analytics_service": {
          "status": 1
        },
        "cloud_messaging_service": {
          "status": 1,
          "apns_config": []
        },
        "appinvite_service": {
          "status": 1,
          "other_platform_oauth_client": []
        },
        "google_signin_service": {
          "status": 1
        },
        "ads_service": {
          "status": 1
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/26?

Comment: I had some of my config files missing analytics info (in fact, the one I listed here doesn't have it).  I decided to answer my own question in case this helps someone in the future.  Thanks for the tips @AaronHe

Answer (score 3):

I figured out my issue, it was that certain flavors didn't have Google Analytics Config info, so apparently the plugin wasn't generating the config files for just that variant.

I double checked each of the flavor's *google-services.json* files, and realized some of them had analytics info (like this):

```
"analytics_service": {
          "status": 2,
          "analytics_property": {
            "tracking_id": "UA-10XXXXX6-1"
          }
        },
```

while others had this (which was incorrect):

```
"analytics_service": {
          "status": 1
        }
```

I made sure both were consistent (and had Analytics config info), and this resolved my build issues.

Comment: This answer solved my problem. I was generating the "google-services.json" file from Firebase. My mistake was using the wrong google account. Use the same google account which has access to the Google Analytics Data.